# Django - Join on specific column

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model, let's call it `Notification`. A notification has a `from_user`, and a `to_user` among other fields which are not important right now.

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='from_user'
    )
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='to_user'
    )
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

What I want to achieve is, in theory, very simple, but I can not get it to work.
I would like to get the count of unread notifications for every user.

The following Django ORM expression:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    notification_count=Count('notification', filter=(Q(notification__read=False)))
).values('notification_count')
```

Produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT("notification"."id") FILTER (WHERE "notification"."read" = False) AS "notification_count" 
FROM "account" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "notification" ON ("account"."id" = "notification"."from_user_id") 
GROUP BY "account"."id" 
ORDER BY "account"."member_since" DESC
```

But this is not what I want.  I want the `LEFT_OUTER_JOIN` to be done on the `to_user` column, not the `from_user` column.

How can I achieve this using the Django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution after trying endless things. Here it is, for anyone who needs it:

```
User.objects.annotate(
    notification_count=Count('to_user', filter=(Q(to_user__read=False)))
).values('notification_count')
```